# q-municate-android (The system cannot find the path specified)

Tags: android, q-municate

I am trying to use the q-municate-android project from GitHub. When I clean the project, I get the following error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':Q- municate_core:transformNative_libsWithSyncJniLibsForRelease'.
 > java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\user\Desktop\Newfolder\QuickBlox\q-municate-android-master\q-municate-android-master\Q-municate_core\build\intermediates\bundles\release\jni\lib\arm64-v8a\libjingle_peerconnection_so.so (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

I am using Windows 10 and Android Studio 1.5.1

The error is: `libjingle_peerconnection_so.so (The system cannot find the path specified)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the gradle version down to 1.3.1. Apparently the problem is with the later versions of gradle (2.x).

Alternatively, the longer way is to:

1) Unzip the native libraries from the jar file. Then remove the jar file.

2) Move the unpacked `lib/<jingle>` folders to `src/main/jniLibs/<jingle>`

(https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=193063)

Comment: is anyone able to elaborate on this method? where do the class objects go, if I put everything from the jar into `jniLibs/sdkname/*`and remove the jar, it fails to build because it can't find the relevant sdk classes. If I leave the jar, it works, as long as I put the .so files in their x86/arm folders in the base of the jniLibs dir